# Copy paste multiple cells doesn't work : Iterate through every cell in the range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a code to copy and paste some values from one spreadsheet to another.
It copies in different column depending on where the value was written and has an index system so that when the sourcesheet is modified the targetsheet is modified in the same row index.
My only issue is : the code doesn't work when multiple cells are copy pasted in the sourcesheet.

The following error shows:

> " Exception: The number of columns in the data does not match the
> number of columns in the range. The data has 2 but the range has 1."

What I want is a way to iterate for every cell in the range the code so that:

- for every row in the modified range it gets the index number in icol and so modify in the target sheet the rows corresponding to the different index numbers
- for every column in the modified range the value of each cell is copied according to the rules (if from col 5 copy to range 2 etc... like written in the code bellow)

Here is my code:

```
function getByName(colName) {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
 var data = sheet.getRange('A3:3').getValues();
 var col = data[0].indexOf(colName);
 if (col != -1) {
   return col+1
 }


function marshall() {

 var spreadsheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();//voir e.
 var sourcesheet= spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
 var range= sourcesheet.getActiveRange();
 var srown= range.getRow();
 var scoln= range.getColumn();
 var value = range.getValues();
 var numCols=range.getNumColumns();
 var numRows=range.getNumRows();


 var targetSpreadheets = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1DUNOBA0KuXird9c2Gl9VX40Nz5UnKXeUTnjTcN0IjzA');
 var targetSheet = targetSpreadheets.getSheetByName('SUIVI MARSHALL 2');

 for (let i = 1; i <= numCols; i++) {
   for (let j = 1; j <= numRows; j++) {
     var cell = range.getCell(j, i);
     var rown=cell.getRow();
     var coln=cell.getColumn();

     Logger.log(cell);

    let icol= getByName("INDEX pour macro Valerie",sourcesheet);
    let ind1=sourcesheet.getRange(rown,icol).getValue(); //index de la ligne modifiée
  
    let listindex= targetSheet.getRange("CD11:CD"); //plage d'index de la colonne d'index dans feuille target
    let r = listindex.createTextFinder(ind1).matchEntireCell(true).findNext();
    let nrow=r.getRow();

    if(coln===3.0){
     let targetcpte = targetSheet.getRange(nrow,1,);
     targetcpte.setValues(value)
     targetSheet.getFilter().sort(2, true);
     targetSheet.getFilter().sort(3, true);
    }
    if(coln===5.0){
      let targetville = targetSheet.getRange(nrow,2);
      targetville.setValues(value)
      targetSheet.getFilter().sort(2, true);
      targetSheet.getFilter().sort(3, true);
    }
    if(coln===6.0){
      let targetdate = targetSheet.getRange(nrow,3);
      targetdate.setValues(value)
      targetSheet.getFilter().sort(2, true);
      targetSheet.getFilter().sort(3, true);
    }
    if(scoln===icol){
      let targetenveloppe = targetSheet.getRange(nrow,4);
      targetenveloppe.setValues(value)
      targetSheet.getFilter().sort(2, true);
      targetSheet.getFilter().sort(3, true);
    }
    
  
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: As far as I can tell there should be: `var cell = range.getCell(j + scoln, i + srown);` It's surprisingly if it works at all without the `srown` and `scoln`. Otherwise the script will start from the cell (1,1) A1 every time.

Comment: The line `var value = range.getValues();` gets you an array (a 2d array). If you set the values from the array with `targetcpte.setValues(value)` it pastes ALL the array into the range `targetcpte`. Probably there should be something like `targetcpte.setValue(value[i+srown][j+scoln])`.

Comment: Please add the textual error message, clearly indicate on which line the error occurs and add some sample data (i.e. the data range values).

Comment: Consider clarifying what cell(s) should be updated depending on what active range you have, it's not clear based on the information you provided. A copy of the spreadsheet you are working on (free of sensitive information) could be helpful.